# Dishwasher depth question

Tags: installation

I'm looking at a new dishwasher.   My current dishwasher is 24.5 inches deep.  The new one would be 22.56 inches deep.  Is this going to be a problem?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. A problem in what sense? What's your concern? Please revise to ask something more specific.

Comment: I'm surprised at 24.5", as standard counter depth is 24".

Comment: Most dishwasher doors reside beyond the depth of the cabinet (at least partially), and the top is usually 25" or deeper.

Answer (score 4):

This should not cause any problems. It just means that the dishwasher will have a little more room in the back for connections if you line it up in the front as the old one was. If the old washer stuck out beyond the front edge of the counter, you'll be able to move it back a bit to line it up flush with the edge.